# How to echo a floating point number within a bash script including the leading 0 before the dot

Tags: bash, floating-point, echo

I am echoing a floating point variable. The results looks as follows:

```
.4983385178
```

I am using echo -e "$var". How can I tell echo also to print the 0 before the dot:

```
0.4983385178
```

Thanks in advance!
Jonas

Comment: To be perfectly correct you are echoing a string. Bash does not understand floating point numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`printf` may help:

```
$ printf '%.10f\n' .4983385178
0.4983385178
```